# Hindman's theorem variant for noncommutative semigroups

Tags: semigroups-and-monoids, infinite-combinatorics

The well set proof of Hindman's finite sums theorem applied to noncommutative semigroups yields a sequence of elements such that finite products ordered coherently with this sequence are in one set. For commutative semigroups it is equivalent with existence of a set with such property (since order doesn't matter ; this was original statement of theorem when it included only natural numbers).

Is there anything said about existence of such set instead of a sequence for noncommutative semigroups?

Comment: A formal wording of the statement you wish to get would help...